# Reload iframe from pop-up window opened from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The Question**

How do I use JS to close a pop-up, opened from an iframe, and then reload the iframe (not the whole page)

**What's been done**

I've opened a pop-up window from within an iframe. 
Once this pop-up window reaches a certain page, I want this pop-up window to reload the IFRAME and then close the pop-up window.

**What I have now**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.opener.parent.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
window.close();
</script>
```

**What is happening now**

The pop-up window closes successfully. The whole page is sent to the iframe URL, instead of just sending it to the iframe...

*edit:*
**What I've tried:**

```
  window.opener.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
```

But, it does not get past this line since the iframe or page does not reload, and it does not close the pop up window. In Chrome, the window closes, but the iframe/page does not reload

Turns out that the page I get to is of a different domain (a different domain that is part of our website). But then, why would this work

```
window.opener.parent.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
```

and not

```
window.opener.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
```

??????

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your code here:

```
window.opener.parent.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
```

- `window` means the current pop-up window's `window` object. Good so far.
- `.opener` means the window object that opened this window, which would be the iframe you want to reload. Still good.
- `.parent` means the parent of the iframe, which is the entire window. This is your problem.

It should be:

```
window.opener.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
```

Comment: This is what I had originally, but there was an error.

In Firefox, when I use
   window.opener.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
it does not get past this line since the iframe or page do not reload, and it does not close the pop up window.

In Chrome, the window closes, but the iframe/page do not reload

Comment: @NolanKnill sounds like a cross-site scripting error. your iframe and the popup window must share the same `document.domain` or you can not execute javascript in between them.

Comment: they are of the same domain, but wouldn't window.opener.parent.location.href NOT work if it were cross-site scripting?

Comment: Actually turns out they are not of the same domain... but why would this work:
`window.opener.parent.location.href="'.urldecode($_GET['return_url']).'";
window.close();`

Comment: @NolanKnill a window and an iframe inside of it are not necessarily the same domain. when dealing with cross site scripting, many properties can be read but not set, and some can not be read or set. in this case, setting the `location.href` of a different domain is not allowed, but accessing the `parent` property is.

Comment: I ended up just using a php workaround to get it back to the proper source... thanks though

Comment: @NolanKnill while i dont think a workaround is the right answer, i am glad you fixed your issue.